# Explicit formula for the summation of a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is there a way to get an explicit formula for the sum after $n$ places of this summation:

$$\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{16} + \frac{9}{64} + \frac{27}{256}... =
\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4^2} + \frac{3^2}{4^3} + \frac{3^3}{4^4}... $$

---

In other words:

$S_1$ would be $\frac{1}{4}$

$S_2$ would be $\frac{7}{16}$

$S_3$ would be $\frac{37}{64}$

$S_n$ would be ?

Comment: What's the common ratio?

Comment: 3/4... assuming it is a series, but it is a sum.   So you're adding 3/4 times the previous term in each step.

Comment: I said common ratio, not common difference

Comment: Right, I'm just saying if this were a series 1/4,3/16,9/64... it would be a geometric sequence and could be recursively defined as An=(A(n-1))*3/4, where A1 = 1/4.   So the common ratio for this series would be 3/4.   But what I am asking for is the summation of the first n terms of this geometric series.

Comment: This series could be explicitly defined as An=((3/4)^n)/3 if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial sum of a geometric series is given by

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} r^{k}=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$

provided $r \neq 1$.  If $r=1$, then the sum is just $n+1$.

To see this, start with

$(1-r)(1+r+r^{2}+\ldots + r^{n})=1 + (r-r) + (r^{2}-r^{2}) + \ldots + (r^{n}-r^{n})-r^{n+1}$.

This "telescoping sum" simplifies to

$(1-r)(1+r+r^{2}+\ldots + r^{n})=1 - r^{n+1}$.

Dividing through by $(1-r)$ (assuming that $r \neq 1$) gives

$1+r+r^{2}+\ldots + r^{n}=\frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1-r}$.

Your sum isn't quite in this form since it starts off with a first term of $1/4$, but it's easy to factor out the $1/4$ and get a geometric series starting with $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Because the initial term is $\frac 14$ and we multiply by $\frac 34$ for each term in our sum, we have

$$S_n = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^n \bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^k$$

We know that summations of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n r^n $ are equal to $\frac{1 - r^{n}}{1-r}$, and so substituting $r=\frac 34$ gives

$$S_n = 1 - (3/4)^{n}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, both your and Brian's answers were very helpful -- I just chose his because it explained it a little bit better for me.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: 
$$
S_n=a\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}q^k-\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}q^k\right)
$$
and $a$, $q$ and the expression for the sum of infinite geometric series you know.